# Creation of a hashmap with struct in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to set up a hashmap of objects / structs in rust... But I don't understand this concrete problem  (a lifetime error).

```
#[derive(Hash, Eq, PartialEq)]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Node<'a> {
    identifier: &'a str,
    sha_id: Vec<u8>,
    successor_id: Option<Vec<u8>>,
    predecessor_id: Option<Vec<u8>>,
}


impl<'a> Node<'a> {
    ...
    ..
    .
}

pub struct Application<'a> {
    hash_map: HashMap<&'a str, Node>,
}

impl<'a> Application<'a> {
    fn join(&self, node: &Node) {
        self.hash_map.insert(node.identifier, node);
    }
}
```

The error is a missing lifetime specifier in  the `hash_map: HashMap<&'a str, Node>` that I tried to solve changing Node to Node<'a> but It throws a "mismatched type" error when I try to insert...

I don't exactly why I have this problem missing the lifetime and I don't find solutions..

**UPDATE:**

```
#[derive(Hash, Eq, PartialEq)]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Node<'a> {
    identifier: &'a str,
    sha_id: Vec<u8>,
    successor_id: Option<Vec<u8>>,
    predecessor_id: Option<Vec<u8>>,
}


impl<'a> Node<'a> {
    ...
    ..
    .
}

pub struct Application<'a> {
    hash_map: HashMap<&'a str, Node<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Application<'a> {
    fn join(&self, node: &Node) {
        self.hash_map.insert(node.identifier, *node);
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
"explicit lifetime required in the type of `node`"
```

**UPDATE2:**

```
pub struct Application<'a> {
    hash_map: HashMap<&'a str, Node<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Application<'a> {
    fn join(&mut self, node: &'a Node<'a>) {
        self.hash_map.insert(node.identifier, *node);
    }

}
```

And the output is:

```
self.hash_map.insert(node.identifier, *node); cannot move out of borrowed content
```

**COMPLETE SOLUTION**

```
#[derive(Clone, Hash, Eq, PartialEq)]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Node<'a> {
    identifier: &'a str,
    sha_id: Vec<u8>,
    successor_id: Option<Vec<u8>>,
    predecessor_id: Option<Vec<u8>>,
}


impl<'a> Node<'a> {
...
..
.
}

pub struct Application<'a> {
    hash_map: HashMap<&'a str, Node<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Application<'a> {
    fn join(&mut self, node: Node<'a>) {
        self.hash_map.insert(node.identifier, node);
    }

}
```

Comment: `insert` takes first the key and then the value...

Comment: sorry, I didn't paste correctly the code.. I edit the post, but the error is the same...

Comment: As far as I understand, `HashMap<&'a str, Node>` should provide a lifetime specifier to `Node` because it requires one by definition. So, it should be `HashMap<&'a str, Node<'a>>`.

Comment: Yes, but when I do this, I get a mismatched type error...  I don't exactly why...

Comment: You have 3 or 4 errors, but if you follow the compiler's advices, you should address all of them.

Comment: I understand that It can be tedious, but in fact, I have only one error, but when I fix one, It throws another one...

Comment: It should be telling you which line requires an explicit lifetime in the error message - my hunch is that the `&Node` on `join` needs to be `&Node<'a>`, or possibly even `&'a Node<'a>`.

Comment: @JoeClay, if you do this, though, Rust will refuse to move out of borrowed content with the last version of the code because, apparently, `insert` attempts to move the second argument.

Comment: Then they need to clone the data, or have the hashmap store references. A `HashMap` always owns the data stored inside of it.

Comment: I can understand this. Directly, it is a bad design... I can try to refactor all the code to   clone data if you think it is the problem...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This simplified example seems to work:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Clone)] // we'll be cloning it later on
struct Node<'a> {
    data: &'a i32 
}


struct Test<'a> {
    hash_map: HashMap<&'a str, Node<'a>>  // the hash map owns the struct
}

impl<'a> Test<'a> {
    fn new() -> Test<'a> {
        Test {hash_map: HashMap::new()}
    }

    fn join(
        &mut self, // must be mutable
        node: Node<'a>) { // do not pass a reference
        self.hash_map.insert("test", node);  // inserting moves `node`
    }
}

fn main() {
    let stuff = Node {data: &12};
    let mut test = Test::new();

    test.join(stuff.clone());  // if we don't clone, `stuff` will get moved

    println!("{}", *test.hash_map["test"].data);  // outputs "12"
}
```

Since `std::collections::HashMap::insert` attempts to move its second argument, one can't dereference a pointer to something and pass that to this method because otherwise the pointer will become uninitialized, which isn't permitted. A way so solve this is to pass a moved value and not a pointer to `join`.

Comment: While your code snippet might answer the question, it would be good if you could add a few sentences what was wrong and how you solved it, at best with some links to documentation or similar problems.

Answer (score 3):

For poor idiots like myself, who are trying to find out how to put hashmaps in a struct, no need to spend many hours "playing" with lifetimes(the `'a` in the above example). They are not required in the slightest, just use String instead of &str in your structure.

**Edit: [@neo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559591/neo) made a slightly clearer version of my below example at [rust-lang](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4c026dce214a85620987b28b07956db6)**

```rust
struct ComputerConfig {
    hostname: String, 
    // displays: Vec<DispConfig>,
}


struct MyConfig {
    pub config_version: u8,
    computers: HashMap<String, ComputerConfig>, // the hash map owns the struct
}

impl MyConfig {
    fn new() -> MyConfig {
        MyConfig {
            computers: HashMap::new(),
            config_version: 1,
        }
    }

    /// Join is used to add a new ComputerConfig into the hashmap
    fn join(
        &mut self, // must be mutable
        key: &str,
        node: ComputerConfig,
    ) {
        // do not pass a reference
        self.computers.insert(key.to_string(), node); // inserting moves `node`
    }
}

fn main() {

  let mut cfg = MyConfig::new()

  cfg.join("test", stuff); 

  println!("{:?}", &cfg); // outputs "12"

}
```

Comment: I guess this answer sort of gives a much cleaner insight into using hashmaps, without the bringing in the complexity of lifetime to it. Ofcourse a little bit more of editing would have been made this perfect. 

I have captured the compiling and running version of @matthew here just for others reference:

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4c026dce214a85620987b28b07956db6